# I try to install geonode using ubuntu 20.04 and i failed in "docker-compose logs -f django"

Tags: django, linux, ubuntu, localhost, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i have an error while loging into geonode in ubuntu 20.04 specifically in the command : docker-compose logs -f django

it stops at this line : MONITORING_DATA_TTL=365 and then exits with code 1

i tried to fix this several times but with no succes

Comment: this usually happens when the DB service is not up, Can you please check if everything is working?